# C Kernel Mode/ring0 - float/double values

Tags: c, kernel

I'm trying to use float or double values in my ring0 c application, but im getting the Linker ERRORs:

Fehler  LNK1120 1 nicht aufgelöste Externe

Fehler  LNK2001 Nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_fltused".

```
float test = 1.2;
```

How can i solve this error?

Comment: Are you sure it is C++ or C? Anyway, assuming this is Linux kernel, float point operations are not supported. You can perform your operations in int or long long if the precision required in fixed.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: The Linux kernel doesn't support "hard" float, i.e. hardware-supported floating point. But especially for ARM, compilers are often capable of "soft" floating point, using library support. That's transparent to the CPU and thus to the kernel.

Comment: Your compiler compiles your program as if it was regular user space program. Since you (probably) have no standard C library for your kernel mode program it is missing some symbols. One solution to that is to avoid using floats and doubles. In many cases it's possible to use integer or fixed point arithmetic instead. You can define `_fltused` as `extern "C" { unsigned int _fltused = 1; }` (you may have to experiment with the exact type) but you'll probably be getting more missing symbols when you write more code.

Comment: Thank you for your fast help! It's a C application, i'm sorry. I started with C++ in this project, then moved to C. The kernel is Windows based. 

And `extern "C" { unsigned int _fltused = 1; }` worked fine for me! Thank you all!

Comment: "The kernel is Windows based." ?? Kernel-mode WDM drivers for Windows must follow certain guidelines when using floating-point operations. These differ between x86 and x64 systems. By default, Windows turns off arithmetic exceptions for both systems.  This page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565388(v=vs.85).aspx might give some hints.

Comment: besides the lack of float support,  this statement: `float test = 1.2;` is trying to assign a `double` value into a `float` variable..  It is highly likely that `double` is also not supported in the kernel.  If `float` were supported, then the line should read: `float test = 1.2f;`  Note the trailing `f` on the literal

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler inserts a dependency on `_fltused` to force you to link with a float support library. Do you have such a library capable of running in ring0?